# Is it relevant to pursue a master degree or a doctorate when applying to a job in the petroleum field?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a few more questions of this type for an interview. ( University work )
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to chemistry.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to acquaint yourself with this page. The question you are asking is outside of our scope and might be a better fit for [academia.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Professional careers in the petroleum industry can be very competitive, so a higher qualification such as masters degree could make you a more attractive candidate for a scientific or engineering position. Many companies nowadays specify post-graduate qualifications as necessary or desirable.

A PhD is generally preferred for research positions.

Comment: While it is certainly nice of you, that you tried to answer this question, it belongs to the [category of questions that should not be asked on this site](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). The proper action with these is to flag them to be closed/ migrated (or vote to close if you have 500 reputation).